# How to constrain a Swift generic type parameter to be any protocol and another parameter to conform to it?

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I'm trying to create a property wrapper for dependency injection:

```
@propertyWrapper struct Dependency<T> {
  private(set) var wrappedValue: T
  init() {
    wrappedValue = Dependencies.shared.resolve()
  }
}

final class Dependencies {
  static let shared = Dependencies()
  private var dependencies = [String: AnyObject]()

  func register<T, P>(_ dependency: T, as: P.Type) {
    let key = String(describing: P.self)
    dependencies[key] = dependency as AnyObject
  }

  func resolve<T>() -> T {
    let key = String(describing: T.self)
    let dependency = dependencies[key] as? T
    precondition(dependency != nil, "No dependency found for \(key)! must register a dependency before resolve.")
    return dependency!
  }
}
```

Where the intention is to register an object that conforms to a protocol and then look that up based on the protocol type.

For example:

```
protocol Foo {
  func foo() -> String
}

class Bar: Foo {
  func foo() -> String {
    "Hello World!"
  }
}

Dependencies.shared.register(Bar(), as: Foo.self)

struct Test {
  @Dependency var a: Foo
}

let t = Test()
print(t.a.foo())
```

This works as expected - printing "Hello World!"

However, I can also do this:

```
Dependencies.shared.register("not a Bar", as: Foo.self)
```

and the precondition blows up since String does not conform to Foo.

What I want to do is constrain `func register<T, P>(_ dependency: T, as: P.Type)` so that T must conform to P.

Something like `register<T: P, P>(_ dependency: T, as: P.Type)` - which obviously doesn't work.

Is this even possible?

Comment: There is not even anything that requires P to be a protocol so even `Dependencies.shared.register("not a Bar", as: Int.self)` would be OK and I think that is the main problem

Comment: @JoakimDanielson but why you'd not want  to have an `Int` dependency? :)

Comment: Related reading: https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-restrict-a-generic-type-parameter-to-only-protocol-types/43263

Comment: This post shows another (comparing to the question) approach to implementing a dependency container using a property wrapper: https://lazarevzubov.medium.com/six-or-so-flavors-of-dependency-injection-in-swift-cd3d72651662

Answer (score 1):

I think this change must do what you expect:

```swift
func register<T>(_ dependency: T, as dependencyType: T.Type) {
  let key = String(describing: dependencyType)
  dependencies[key] = dependency as AnyObject
}
```

(The rest of your code stays unchanged.)

Then this line that bothers you doesn't compile (`Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'Bar'`):

```swift
Dependencies.shared.register("not a Bar", as: Bar.self)
```

Comment: Does this work for valid registrations:`Dependencies.shared.register(Bar(), as: Foo.self)`?

Comment: Yes. I copied the entire original code to Playgrounds (including usage), made the change from the answer and got, I believe, expected output.